# Do the Phrases "Entitled to" and "Eligible for" Mean the Same Thing?

Tags: synonyms, syntactic-analysis

It comes up in the Supreme Court Couse Bacerra vs. Empire Health Foundation.
Here is some example context:

"Person x is ENTITLED TO medical assistance"

and

"Person x is ELIGIBLE FOR medical assistance"

Do those 2 sentences mean the same thing?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a second to read about [the topics covered here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions about meaning are off-topic unless you show that you have looked the word(s) up in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain. Entitlement and eligibility are different concepts, though the end result in this sentence is similar.

Answer (score 1):

*Entitled to* and *Eligible for* have similar meanings, but not the same.

*Entitled to* means that person X has the legal right to medical assistance; Person X legally has this right and benefit.

From the Merriam Webster dictionary, entitled is defined as:

> : having a right to certain benefits or privileges

*Eligible for* means person X could legally *apply* for this right to medical assistance; person X qualifies to have this legal right.

From the Merriam Webster dictionary, eligible is defined as:

> : qualified to participate or be chosen

Being eligible for the medical assistance means that person X qualifies for the assistance, and can legally apply for this right. However, it does not mean that the person *has* this right, ie. the person might be eligible for the right, but has not *applied for* the right.